# My wordpress website shows wamp server detials when clicking on each page except home page

Tags: php, wordpress, wamp

I downloaded my website from server to configure in local server, after that I did search and replace.
Now the website shows the home page but when I click on each page it shows wamp server details.
I do not know how to handle this problem.
[image]

I have read that go to dashboard, setting, permalink and then save but it did not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried myself to solve my problem. I have saved so many times the permalinks in setting part, but it did not work for me as other people mentioned to do this. I just changed my database name and again saved the permalinks in setting parts and finally it works for me.